# "Was denken Sie" vs. "Wie denken Sie"

Tags: grammaticality

This could be a duplicate but I haven't found one.

My German-Japanese dictionary lists both *Was denken Sie?* and *Wie denken Sie?* as expressions to ask for an opinion. Combined with searches on the web, I think both are actually acceptable forms. But I noticed Langenscheidt has only *Was denken Sie?*.

My questions are:

1. Are both acceptable as an equivalent to English *What do you think*?
2. Is there any difference in meaning or occasion where they are used?
3. (If *Wie..* is accpetable) In my understanding, *How do you think?* in English is considered wrong. If *Wie denken Sie?* is grammatically wrong in the same way, why is it acceptable?

Comment: Both are grammatically fine, but "was denken Sie über..." is used _much_ more commonly than "wie denken Sie über...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Was* means *what* and is asking for an object.

> Was denken Sie?
> What do you think?

So that's an open question about your thoughts (e.g. your opinion).

*Wie* means *how* and is asking for a method, a manner, a way - in German *Art und Weise*.

> Wie denken Sie?
> How do you think?

is therefore not asking for an opinion or your thoughts. It's rather asking about the subject of thinking itself.

However, for a given subject you can ask:

> Wie denken Sie **darüber**?
> (or *Was halten Sie davon?*)

That would mean something like: *Do you think, it's a good idea?* / Do you think, I am right? ...

There is nothing wrong with the grammar. *Wie denken Sie* is just not asking for an opinion.

Comment: In your last example, the thing being asked is the object (noun phrase) of _denken_. So doesn't that mean _wie_ is inappropriate?

Comment: No. In *Wie denken Sie **darüber**?* the *darüber* refers to something that was already said. And now someone wants to know your valuation. That implies usually reasoning about how you come to your conclusion.

Comment: In English, _how do you think of/about it_ is considered wrong as well (if I'm not mistaken). Any idea why the difference?

Comment: No. Sorry. No idea. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, "was" means "what" and "wie" means "how". So I would prefer "was".

I can imagine using "how" when the question ask more about the though process and less about the result.

There may also be regional differences.